# wc_create_order can't seem to call any functions on order created

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create an order with an ajax call.

The order seems to get created. `$order->id` is filled in with a valid number and I can redirect to that URL and edit.  But my problem is I can't seem to call any methods on the object. As soon as I call `$order->save();` or `$order->set_billing_first_name('Leo');`. I get Call to undefined function save(). Then I get a 500 returned to ajax call.

```
$order = wc_create_order();

if (is_wp_error( $order )) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => 'Order was not created. ERROR: '.$order->get_error_message()));
    die();
}

$order->billing_first_name = $firstName;
$order->save();


$url = admin_url( 'post.php?post='.$order->id.'&action=edit' );

echo json_encode(array('error' => '', 'url' => $url));
die();
```

Is there a way around this Or what is going on?
thanks
Leo

Comment: Search in [`WC_Checkout` class the `create_order()` function…](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#247-335) … This will help you to understand. There is also 2 or 3 hooks as you will see…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the WC_Order object seems to have changed. Many of the examples out there no longer will work.

So My solution ended up being.

```
    $order->set_address($billing_address, 'billing');
```

So I guess the moral is to look at the code itself instead of trusting the docs.